# Count the failed login attemps and lockout user in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-authentication, django-login

I am trying to count the number of invalid login attempts using "user_login_failed_callback" method. As shown the code below, I am trying to access previous database field value of "failed_login_count" from "user_login_failed_callback" method. I will update the value of failed_login_count to failed_login_count+1 and also update the date and time to current time.

Currently I am accessing "failed_login_count" from "user.get_profile()". I know which is wrong. Could you please point the right way to access BruteForceEntry model fields failed_login_count.

My questions are

1. So could you please let me know how can I access failed_login_count from database and update the existing value.
2. As shown in below code I am using "BruteForceEntry.objects.filter" to update existing database row. So is this the correct way to update table.
3. How can I lock out user account after more than 10 failed login attemps.

Could you please help me.

```html
class BruteForceEntry(models.Model):

    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=256, null=True)
    data_time_of_last_unsuccessful_login = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, blank=True)
    failed_login_count = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return '{0} - {1} - {2}'.format(self.username, self.data_time_of_last_unsuccessful_login, self.failed_login_count)

    def __str__(self):
        return '{0} - {1} - {2}'.format(self.username, self.data_time_of_last_unsuccessful_login, self.failed_login_count)

@receiver(user_login_failed)
def user_login_failed_callback(sender, credentials, **kwargs):
    username = credentials['username']
    user = User.objects.get(username=username)
    profile = user.get_profile()
    failed_login_count = profile.failed_login_count + 1

    BruteForceEntry.objects.filter(username=username).update(data_time_of_last_unsuccessful_login=timezone.now(), failed_login_count=failed_login_count)
```

Comment: 1) looks like an easy way to lock all the users of this website by simply "attempting" to login with wrong password; think about locking IP or something like this  2) there is fail2ban and other app that can do this job